# How can I get the function $g(z)$ which satisfies following properties?

Tags: complex-analysis

$g(z)$ is a complex function which is holomorphic on $\mathbb C$ and for all $ρ>0$ there exists a constant number $M$ and positive integer $k$ such that:
$$\max_{z\in \mathbb C, |z|=ρ} |g(z)| \leq Mρ^k$$

Comment: You could choose $g(z)=Mz^k$.

Comment: Is that all? How can I prove there is no another $g(z)$?

Comment: Apply Liouville to $g(z)/z^k$.